# JSON and Python - flatten JSON api for CSV with TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, api

Trying to flatten JSON-formatted data rec'd via API with a somewhat unpredictable hierarchy with the goal of saving it as a CSV for import into MySQL and I'm running into an error ***TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str***

- data1 is a list with the results of the API call ...

CODE:

```
    json_data1 = json.dumps(data1)

## Flatten JSON

from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

outfile = open("output.csv", "w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")

data = json.loads(json_data1, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

# Recursively flatten JSON
def flatten(structure, key="", path="", flattened=None): 
    if flattened is None:
        flattened = OrderedDict()    
    if type(structure) not in(OrderedDict, list):
        flattened[((path + "_") if path else "") + key] = structure    
    elif isinstance(structure, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(structure):
            flatten(item, "", path + "_" + key, flattened)    
    else:
        for new_key, value in structure.items():
            flatten(value, new_key, path + "_" + key, flattened)    
    return flattened

# Write fields
fields = []
for result in data["results"]:
    flattened = flatten(data["results"][0])
    for k, v in flattened.iteritems():
        if k not in fields:
            fields.append(k)
writer.writerow(fields)

# Write values
for result in data["results"]:
    flattened = flatten(result)
    row = []
    for field in fields:
        if field in flattened.iterkeys():
            row.append(flattened[field])
        else:
            row.append("")
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Any ideas on where the error is?

Comment: You need to post a sample of the JSON and the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan said, you're probably expecting a dict but actually feed in an array.

If that's the case then you should be able to simply take out the "results" bits as follows:

```
[...]
# Write fields
fields = []
for result in data:
    flattened = flatten(result)
[...]
```

I found a block of code very similar to yours at https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/152036/Flatten-JSON-and-output-as-CSV that worked for me once I took out the "results". I'm guessing you managed to make it work in the meantime, but this might still help others looking to convert JSON to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to post more output for someone to troubleshoot this.  What line number is the error on?

In general this error means you're trying to pass a non integer value in a list.  For example, if you have list:

list = ["a", "b", "c"]

You can do list[0] to get "a".  If you do list["pig"] you get "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str".

Just add some print statements before your lists and you should be able to spot this.

Comment: Error happens at 'for result in data["results"]:'

Comment: Print your "data" and see what it looks like.  It's probably an array but you are expecting it to be a dict

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the pandas method `json_normalize`.
It flattens the json without much pain.

[Check the documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

You can convert the json to csv in the following way:

```
df = json_normalize(json_obj)
df.to_csv("file.csv",sep=",")
```